# Store NSArray to file when transiting between two view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iPhone App, and there are two view controllers in my code, let them be ViewControllerA(VCA) and ViewControllerB(VCB), VCA can push to VCB with a segue, and VCB can return to VCA. the following are the code in my VCA:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"placePiece"]) {
        VCB *vcb = (VCB*) segue.destinationViewController;
        vcb.shipsOnBoard = indexRecorder;
    }
}
```

When arrived at VCB, I will do something there. What I wanna do is to save data in VCB, I want to start saving when user clicks the back button in upper left corner of VCB, I tried to do it in the prepareForSegue method in VCB, but it seems that method is not called. Furthermore, I also want to start reading data when user go to VCB again, I want to know which method will be called when each time user go from VCA to VCB and vise versa, so that I can do the read and write thing there. Thanks.

Comment: what is wustlPPVC? Shouldn't that be vcb?

Comment: prepareForSegue is the right place to do this.  Agree with @Prakash, "vcb" is view controller on which to set the property.

Comment: @Prakash I changed it, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, when you push a view controller and then go back from there to the previous view controller you aren't using a segue, so `prepareForSegue` won't be called. Instead, you should look at using `willMoveToParentViewController:`. When the parent view controller is being set to `nil` then the current view controller is being popped from the stack. At this point you can call methods on the parent view controller to update it with state information.

`willMoveToParentViewController:` will also be called when VCB is created and displayed (added to the stack during the segue).

Another way to do this would be to set VCA as the `delegate` of VCB, and have VCB update the `delegate` after pertinent changes.

Comment: Use delegates! Delegates are awesome!